# Process creation and control - Synchronization

Tags: c

I have a problem in this question
You are to implement a code cracking system. The system will deploy four processes
(p1,p2,p3 & p4) to try to guess the password of an encrypted code.
For encryption, we consider that the formula is: C = P XOR K, where

```
C = encrypted code
P = plain text
K = key
```

For decryption the formula is: P = C XOR K. So, your program will try to find K using
this formula. The XOR operator is ^.
Given an encrypted code C and plain code P your program should deploy three processes
to try and find the key used to encrypt the plain code. These three processes will be under
the control of process P1.
All processes will send their results to process P1 and process P1 will terminate the three
processes and display the encryption key and decrypted text once any of the three
processes finds the key.
For simplicity we will consider that we have the original number P stored in a file called
plain.txt and the encrypted code is stored in a file called cipher.txt. Consider that only
numbers are stored in these files and they have a range between 0 and 100000000.
So we have P and C your program should find the key K. Consider that K is a positive
number between 0 and 1000000.

My question is how many semaphore can I use? and whats the value of each one??
I don't need to help me with code just the number of semaphore

Comment: Why are you dumping large amounts of unrelated homework on us when you're actually trying to understand how semaphores work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I could to that without semaphores, but I guess that's not the task... ;)

Comment: ok, true when one of the 3 process find the key the parent process kill it. but why I need three process if I'm not using semaphore?

Comment: You need 3 processes so the 3 workers can run independently; the semaphore is the mechanism used to tell P1 when the job is done, so it can terminate the workers.  I think Mats is saying he could accomplish that communication w/o a semaphore.

Comment: It's right that using only pipe witout semaphore? and when one of these process find K tell the parent process and send the value by pipe?

Answer (score 1):

If this is an accurate reduction of the problem:

> Once any of 3 worker processes completes its work, the master process
>   terminates all 3 workers

then you should only need 1 semaphore, which the master will wait on, and every worker will signal when finished, the first of which which will unblock the master so it can terminate the workers.  In fact, you only need a mutex, and not a full semaphore.

Comment: ok, true when one of the 3 process find the key the parent process kill it. but why I need three process if I'm not using semaphore?